# Does XML + LINQ will give me good performance with large amounts of data in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm currently making decison what way of storing data, created and used by my app, to choose. I rather  want to avoid using any RDBMS as separate server running on machine already as service that my app would connect to, i mean i rather got on my mind some database engine that would consist on a file, but i would like to avoid MS Acess or any other platform that aren't multiplatform/open source/free.

I thought to use XML file  combined with LINQ to store and acces that data, but the information in the XML file, as i expect will go into large size on disk and big amount of entries depending on user activity.

I'm worried of memory load, CPU usage and access/operation speed as XML file grow.

If XML file is bad idea, then what independent, free and easy way of storing data on which application will operate i might use?

Thanks in advance
MTH

Comment: in-memory database? SQLlite, SQL Server CE?

Comment: SQLite will be a far more robust (being ACID compliant) and flexible solution- the XML file(s) may become corrupted and then you will lose all your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) or [SQL CE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact).

It's free and is portable as another dll(s) file with your project, and has ADO.NET/EF support.

Learn how to use SQLite with .NET:

- http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/afenster/185/Default.aspx

Answer (score 4):

XML isn't bad, but you could still take advantage of a database system like [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)/[System.Data.SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) that is compact, portable, multi-platform and can be used with Entity Framework or another ORM.

Answer (score 1):

Like Mitch said, you should take a look on [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org), which has a [nice port for .NET](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/). With SQLite, you can store your data in the RDBMS way, without the issue of needing costly servers or even installing a process in the PC.

You can use ADO.NET for accesing your SQLite data or nHibernate, but for your question, I sense that nHibernate is way to heavy for your purpouses. On small addition, if you want a small helper class to handle the database queries, I wrote [this](http://davidcondemarin.blogspot.com/2010/12/simple-class-for-data-access-using.html) blog article with a light class for those purpouses.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at SQLite.  It is free and has many freely available management tools.
You can download Sqlite for ADO.Net from sourceforge.  I am currently using Sqlite as a database and connecting to it using Habanero.  Habanero is an object relational mapper (actually it's a meta data mapper).  It hides all that nasty data access code and allows you to concentrate on your domain objects.  Habanero is open source and has a management front end (called FireStarter Modeller) for creating your domain layer.  Note you don't need to use Habanero.  You can just as easily use ADO directly referencing the System.DataSQLite.dll which supports all the common ADO.Net interfaces.  I wouldn't be surprise if there is a linq provider for SQLite as well.

Linq to Xml is very cool, but I still think you would be better off using a relational database.